# issue when % character is in url

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, routes

the site I am developing has routes with parameters such as:

http://localhost:4200/v1/script/start=20170503&end=20170509&source=testname

Some of these parameters the user can create themselves such a "source". I encode these values so if the user defined a source=%%PAGE%% it would show up in the url as source=%2525%2525PAGE%2525%2525. The problem I encountered was if i manually typed the url: http://localhost:4200/v1/script/start=20170503&end=20170509&source=%%PAGE%% without encoding the % signs i get this error:

URIError: URI malformed
    at decodeURIComponent (native)
    at getFilenameFromUrl (C:\Users\name\Sites\dashboard\node_modules\webpack-dev-middleware\lib\GetFilenameFromUrl.js:6:8)
    at webpackDevMiddleware (C:\Users\name\Sites\dashboard\node_modules\webpack-dev-middleware\middleware.js:39:18)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\name\Sites\dashboard\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at trim_prefix (C:\Users\name\Sites\dashboard\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:317:13)
    at C:\Users\name\Sites\anura-dashboard\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:284:7
    at Function.process_params (C:\Users\name\Sites\dashboard\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:335:12)
    at next (C:\Users\name\Sites\dashboard\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:275:10)
    at next (C:\Users\name\Sites\dashboard\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:127:14)
    at next (C:\Users\name\Sites\dashboard\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:131:14)
    at next (C:\Users\name\Sites\dashboard\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:131:14)
    at next (C:\Users\name\Sites\dashboard\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:131:14)
    at next (C:\Users\name\Sites\dashboard\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:131:14)
    at next (C:\Users\name\Sites\dashboard\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:131:14)
    at next (C:\Users\name\Sites\dashboard\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:131:14)
    at next (C:\Users\name\Sites\dashboard\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:131:14)

I would like to catch this error and either remove the source or log the user out, rather than getting a blank screen and a javascript error.

Comment: It looks to me like you are encoding characters in your URL twice and then trying to decode them. `%2525%2525PAGE%2525%2525` decodes to `%25%25PAGE%25%25`. I haven't gotten around to learning express yet, but I'm willing to bet it already decodes your URL, and your code is trying to decode a decoded URL - resulting in that error.

Answer (score 0):

I feel like this might not be the best way to handle things, but I got it to work nonetheless:

try {

```
this.source = decodeURIComponent( urlParams['source'] );
```

);

} catch( error ) {

```
this.source = urlParams['source'];
```

}